# Extract specific object properties into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

How to convert the object `{ CntDay: 0, CntMonth: 2, CntYear: 4 }` to the array `[ 0, 2, 4 ]`?

I am getting my data in the `events` array but I need the array to not form like `{ CntDay: 0, CntMonth: 2, CntYear: 4 }` but simply like `[ 0, 2, 4 ]`.

```
function createChartWinLoss() {
  var events = [];

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Dashboard.aspx/NewChart",
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data.d, function(i, v) {
        events.push({
          CntDay: v.CntDay,
          CntMonth: v.CntMonth,
          CntYear: v.CntYear
        });
      })
      ChartProp(events)
    }
  });
}

function ChartProp(events) {
  var a = $.map(events, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
  });
}
```

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to push a different object to the `events` array.

```js
function createChartWinLoss() {
  var events = [];
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Dashboard.aspx/NewChart",
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data.d, function(i, v) {
        // here push an array, instead of an object
        //events.push({
        //  CntDay: v.CntDay,
        //  CntMonth: v.CntMonth,
        //  CntYear: v.CntYear
        //});
        
        events.push([
          v.CntDay,
          v.CntMonth,
          v.CntYear
        ])
        
      })
      
      ChartProp(events)
    }
  });
}

function ChartProp(events) {
  //var a = $.map(events, function(value, index) {
  //  return [value];
  //});
  
  console.log({events: events})

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Object.values(data). It directly creates an array of all the values present in your object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values